# 26. How do I compute a partial integral across a 2D matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, integral

I have a 2D matrix, Z(x,y) from which I need to compute the equation:

[image]

I do this using the code:

```
Sa        = nansum(nansum(abs(Z - Zbar))) / (nX*nY);
```

N/B: I am using `nansum` because `Z(x,y)` contains some `NaN` values.

Now, I’m finding it difficult to compute the equation:

[image]

I tried to break the equation down with the following code:

```
% compute the partial sums in the equation
for jj = 1: nY-1
    for ii = 1: nX-1
        Z_abt(jj,ii) = ( Z(jj,ii)- Z(jj,ii+1) )^2 + ( Z(jj,ii)- Z(jj+1,ii) )^2;       
    end
end

% compute Sdr
Sdr = nansum( nansum( sqrt(1+Z_abt) - 1) );
```

`Sdr` values are always supposed to be fractions, but I am getting ridiculously large values Instead.

I’m just wondering if I really need a loop to do this and how I could go about that?

Comment: I think you missed the `1/A` in the equation. Also the `dx dy`. Integrating is summing over the matrix, then multiply by the step size (distance between matrix elements).

Comment: Thank you @Cris for those observations. I have added in `1/A` and the values reduces to about `100`, which off course is still very large. `dxdy = 1` in all cases i guess, hence, doesn't change the computation. Going forward, i still think i'm doing something wrong somewhere in the computation of the partial sum.